# Best approach to use Model in Angular2+

Tags: angular

I am using angular since v2 and I use direct method for variable assign though HTTP. I know I should use model class but I have a certain problem with it that is if some variable of a model (property) is not present in JSON then it breaks.?

DI is not meant to used here.? How should the model be designed so that when I add a new variable to a model (property) it don't break?

How you design your app and model?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a contact model.You can use model as:

```
export class SimpleContact {
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    Email: string;
    Phone: number;
    constructor(obj?: any) {
        this.FirstName = (obj && obj.FirstName) || '';
        this.LastName = (obj && obj.LastName) || '';
        this.Email = (obj && obj.Email) || '';
        this.Phone = (obj && obj.Phone) || null;
    }
}
```

So if any value is not present in the API data then it will either assign a null or empty value.If your API data is much more nested e.g if the `Email` field is inside a field called `Address` suppose then you can do as:

```
this.Email = (obj && obj.Address && obj.Address.Email) || '';
```

So now to use this model in any component you can invoke as

```
let contact = new SimpleContact(data);
```

Also you can use this model in another model if it is required.So suppose if you have an `Address` model that should contain the `SimpleContact` model we have described above then you can create the model as:

```
export class Address {
    Line1: string;
    City: string;
    PostCode: number;
    Country: string;
    Contact: SimpleContact; //here we are using the model

    constructor(obj?: any) {
        this.Line1 = (obj && obj.Line1) || '';
        this.City = (obj && obj.City) || '';
        this.PostCode = (obj && obj.PostCode) || null;
        this.Country = (obj && obj.Country) || '';
        this.Contact = new SimpleContact(obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I got following solutions:-

Model could be like this with id and name where both have predefined null values

```
export class Hero {
  constructor(public id: number = null,
              public name: string = null) { }
}
```

Then after some time, if we add new property like power

```
export class Hero {
  constructor(public id: number = null,
              public name: string = null,
              public power: string = null) { }
}
```

Nothing breaks. You don't even have to change previous codes which don't use power property.

Is this good way of doing it?

And ya you now can't just assign new array or object without power property directly to it. we have to do something like `hero = new Hero(1, 'Superman');` with two arguments or three as per requirement. and if JSON changes, we have to manually add new variable to Hero method. Is there a better way??